# It is safe to call a member function on a vtkObject after I call Delete function?

Tags: c++, vtk

The following code comes from vtkAbstractTransform. My application crushed in this function, Is this code safe?

```
 void vtkTransformConcatenation::Concatenate(const double elements[16])
    {
    // concatenate the matrix with either the Pre- or PostMatrix
    if (this->PreMultiplyFlag)
    {
        if (this->PreMatrix == NULL)
        {
            // add the matrix to the concatenation
            vtkSimpleTransform *mtrans = vtkSimpleTransform::New();
            this->Concatenate(mtrans);
            mtrans->Delete(); // call Delete on mtrans
            this->PreMatrixTransform = mtrans;
            this->PreMatrix = mtrans->GetMatrix();
        }
        vtkMatrix4x4::Multiply4x4(*this->PreMatrix->Element, elements,
                              *this->PreMatrix->Element); // My application crushed here.
       ...
    } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually it doesn't make sense to call the function over deleted object. After deleting the object this assignment

```
 this->PreMatrixTransform = mtrans;
```

usually had put garbage values (possibly NULL value) in  this->PreMatrixTransform. and when this variable is used (I am pretty sure) it will cause crash.

Answer (score 0):

No. Calling `Delete` may delete the object. Accessing a deleted object invokes undefined behaviour.